# How can I compare an instance of a class to a type of interface?

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I'm attempting to implement a simple service locator in Kotlin, based on [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-service-locator-pattern), except I want to use generic type parameters. I'm also trying to avoid inlining the functions with reified type parameters because that requires everything to be public.

This class is responsible for caching instances of located services:

```
class Cache {
    private val services: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()

    fun <T> getService(serviceClass: Class<T>): T? {
        val service = services.firstOrNull { s -> s::class.java == serviceClass }

        if (service != null) {
            return service as T
        }

        return null
    }

    fun addService(service: Any) {
        services.add(service)
    }
}
```

This is how the cache is being called:

```
cache.getService(IMyService::class)
```

It returns null everytime, regardless of whether it contains an instance of `MyService` or not. The problem is on `s::class.java == serviceClass`, because at runtime the cache contains an instance `MyService`, and `MyService::class.java` is not equivalent to `IMyService::class` (nor is `MyService::class` - I tried that too).

I tried modifying the `getService` method like so:

```
fun <T> getService(): T? {
    val service = services.firstOrNull { s -> s is T }

    if (service != null) {
        return service as T
    }

    return null
}
```

On `s is T`, the compiler complains "Cannot check for instance of erased type: T". How can I make this work without inlining, which would require the list of services to be made public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're okay with the reflection, you can use [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) to check if the `Class` requested is a superclass/superinterface of a given `Class` that you have cached:

```
fun <T> getService(serviceClass: Class<T>): T? {
    return services.firstOrNull { s -> serviceClass.isAssignableFrom(s::class.java) } as T?
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `serviceClass.isInstance(s)` would do the same thing.

Comment: Is there any reason I would want to avoid reflection in this case?

Comment: I don't think there is any more reason to avoid it here than anywhere else in general, if you're not using reified, this is the way to do it. Some people just tend to avoid reflection for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer the other half of the question about inlining, you can avoid making the services map public by using the `@PublishedApi` annotation and marking the field `internal`. For example:

```
class Cache {
    @PublishedApi internal val services: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()

    inline fun <reified T> getService(serviceClass: Class<T>): T? {
        return T::class.java.let { it.cast(services.firstOrNull(it::isInstance)) }
    }

    fun addService(service: Any) {
        services.add(service)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to kcoppock's great idea with the [`@PublishedApi`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-published-api/index.html) annotation you could use `is` as well, avoiding reflection and making the function really concise:

```
class Cache {
    @PublishedApi internal val services: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()

    inline fun <reified T> getService() = services.firstOrNull { it is T } as T?

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `services` private (or to make `getService` usable from Java), and still keep better usability from Kotlin, just add an overload:

```
fun <T> getService(serviceClass: Class<T>): T? { ... }

inline fun <reified T> getService(): T? = getService(T::class.java)
```